# Update post is not working in while it works with update user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Creating a image posting website in which is have to put update post option but after trying many I don't know what is happening and I have checked the query it is all right.

I'm using php7 and mysql database.

Here I trigger the edit post and update post option

```
if (isset($_GET['edit-post'])) {
    $isEditingPost = true;
    $post_id = $_GET['edit-post'];
    editPost($post_id);
}
// if user clicks the update post button
if (isset($_POST['update_post'])) {
    updatePost($_POST);
}
```

And My code For Update Post is here

```
function updatePost($request_values)
    {
global $conn, $errors, $post_id, $title, $featured_image, $topic_id, $published;

                $title = esc($request_values['title']);
        //$body = esc($request_values['body']);
        $post_id = esc($request_values['post_id']);
        if (isset($request_values['topic_id'])) {
            $topic_id = esc($request_values['topic_id']);
        }
        // create slug: if title is "The Storm Is Over", return "the-storm-is-over" as slug
        $post_slug = makeSlug($title);

        if (empty($title)) { array_push($errors, "Post title is required"); }
        //if (empty($body)) { array_push($errors, "Post body is required"); }
        // if new featured image has been provided
        if (isset($_POST['featured_image'])) {
            // Get image name
            $featured_image = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
            // image file directory
            $target = "../static/images/" . basename($featured_image);
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image. Please check file settings for your server");
            }
        }

        // register topic if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $query = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', slug='$post_slug', image='$featured_image', published=$published, updated_at=now() WHERE id=$post_id";
            // attach topic to post on post_topic table
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ // if post created successfully
                if (isset($topic_id)) {
                    $inserted_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    // create relationship between post and topic
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO post_topic (post_id, topic_id) VALUES($inserted_post_id, $topic_id)";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Post created successfully";
                    header('location: posts.php');
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Post updated successfully";
            header('location: posts.php');
            exit(0);
        }
    }
```

here I submit my code

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update_post">UPDATE</button>
```

I have taken ref from [Here](https://codewithawa.com/posts/how-to-create-a-blog-in-php-and-mysql-database---admin-posts)

=============Errors==============================

```
Notice: Undefined index: post_id in D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\post_functions.php on line 169

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to esc() must be of the type string, null given, called in D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\post_functions.php on line 169 and defined in D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\admin_functions.php:301 Stack trace: #0 D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\post_functions.php(169): esc(NULL) #1 D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\post_functions.php(69): updatePost(Array) #2 D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\create_post.php(4): include('D:\\newphp\\htdoc...') #3 {main} thrown in D:\newphp\htdocs\social\admin\includes\admin_functions.php on line 301
```

the esc funtion is on line: 301

````
function esc(String $value){
    // bring the global db connect object into function
    global $conn;
    // remove empty space sorrounding string
    $val = trim($value); 
    $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $val);
    return $val;
}```
````

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This is a really bad tutorial and you should stop following it immediately.

Comment: hey, @Dharman thanks for suggestions. Can You please help me with this code.

Comment: I am afraid I do not know what is your problem. You have not posted any errors or expected and observed behaviour. Not enough details to go on.

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id()` is not set when doing an `UPDATE`, only when doing `INSERT`. If you're updating an existing post, you shouldn't need to do anything to `post_topic`, the post should already be there.

Comment: Is this an academic project, or something you're intending to deploy? If it's academic there's a lot of bad habits here you need to unlearn. If it's for deployment this code is too risky to deploy and another approach should be used.

Comment: Hey, @Barmar post_topic thanks I will do that.

Comment: @tadman this is just for learning. I am newbie to php hope you would understand.

Comment: Nothing wrong with learning, but it looks like the resources you're using to learn are wickedly out of date. Consider using [PHP the Right Way](https://phptherightway.com) as a starting point and make an effort to avoid using the first random tutorial or video you come across. These are usually dangerously insecure and full of mistakes.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Show us your HTML form. Look like it isn't sending `post_id`.